# Can HP Proliant G9 server use RAMs of different clock speeds

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

We got a bunch of HP Proliant 360 G9 servers which needs to be upgraded. Existing RAM modules are dual rank 2133MHz, vendor is suggesting to add on 2400MHz RAMs but rest of specs seems to be same.

Would 2400MHz modules under-clock and work together with 2133MHZ modules?

Additional info: `dmidecode -t memory` on these linux servers show configured clock speed as 1866MHz for existing modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use HPE RAM for ProLiant Gen9 servers.

This is the right thing to do for support purposes, performance and general health.

Read the [HPE ProLient DL360 Gen9 Quickspecs](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04346229.pdf).

Assuming your vendor is competent, they should be matching the RAM to one of the existing SKUs and recommending you follow HP's DIMM population guidelines and compatibility rules.

---

Edit:

You should be using 728629-B21 instead of 805351-B21. But that depends on your CPU model. If it's a v3 CPU, buy more DDR-2133. If you have a v4 CPU, thinks are optimized for DDR4-2400. Either will work, and will clock to the speed your CPU supports.

[image]

Comment: Existing RAM is HP, proposed RAM is also HP. Normally we assume if vendor suggests it should work, but different clock speed and SKU number makes me uneasy. If it were to fail they have to find a part that will work but it will cause a delay in the project of course. For PC I know you can configure then mix and match, server is a whole different game.

Comment: Please provide the part numbers.

Comment: Server 755258-B21,  existing RAM 752369-081, proposed RAM 805351-B21

Comment: Okay. See my edit.